# My java application wont display any output from the mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, database, ssl, database-connection

My code is as follows

```
import java.sql.*;


public class jbdcTrial {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String dburl ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users";
        String username ="root";
        String password ="Calvin25;";


        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection myconnection = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl,username,password);


            Statement myStatement = myconnection.createStatement();


            ResultSet myresultset = myStatement.executeQuery("select * from employees");

            while(myresultset.next()) {
                 int count =myresultset.getInt(1);
                 System.out.println("count of stock : " + count);

            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {


        }

    }
}
```

I have mysql connector added in eclipse as a jar library
the only output i see is this

> Tue Feb 27 17:44:23 EAT 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.

But in the tutorial it displays output from the database plus that warning

Comment: Also, this is evil code: `catch (SQLException e) {}` Always handle such exceptions, else you're flying blind. At least print the stack trace: `catch (SQLException e) { e.printStacktrace(); }`

Comment: Even when i add catch (SQLException e) { e.printStacktrace(); } in my code there is still no output from the database

Comment: Did you make the changes suggested in the answers to the possible duplicate?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
String dburl ="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?useSSL=false";
```

Comment: This is probably a duplicate though.

Comment: This is the EXACT answer in the duplicate. Please don't do this. Read the duplicate first. I had a link to the duplicate in my first comment made over 20 minutes ago. Question now closed with it.

Comment: Yes sir, thank you sir.

Comment: I don't think a downvote is necessary for a CORRECT answer.  But I'll be sure to check the comments next time.

Comment: Your answer provides no explanation, nothing that makes it useful to future visitors. That is the main reason for this down vote

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Totally agree in retrospect.